# How to get Memory Stream/Base64 String from Image.Source?

Tags: silverlight

I have a dynamically created Image control that is populated via a OpenFileDialog like:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (FileStream stream = dialog.File.OpenRead())
    {                    
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(stream);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

I want to send the image back to the server in a separate function call, as string via a web service.

**How do I get a memory stream / base64 string from myImage.Source**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an alternative which should work (without BmpBitmapEncoder). It's uses the FileStream stream to create the byte array that is then converted to a Base64 string. This assumes you want to do this within the scope of the current code.

```
  Byte[] bytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
  stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: I think you mean stream.read(), where stream is FileStream, instead of mem.write(). but yes this works without the use of additional DLLs.

Comment: no need for memory stream. I did: Byte[] bytes = new Byte[stream.Length]; stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); serialized = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Then you can do this:

```
ImageSource myStartImage;

var image = ((WriteableBitmap) myStartImage).ToImage();
var encoder = new PngEncoder( false );

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Encode( image, stream );

var myStartImageByteStream = stream.GetBuffer();
```

Then for Base64:

```
string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(myStartImageByteStream);
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer however I think the Base64 bit is probably red-herring, pumping the stream directly to the server would be better.

Comment: This looks promising and the DLLs are very small in size too. Thanks will try it now

Comment: AnthonyWJones- with a Windows app you could do it, but I think Silverlight does not support streamed WCF calls.