# Parse image to byte array and send to web service

Tags: silverlight, image, parsing, arrays, bitmapimage

I am wondering how I can get an image from a Silverlight Image control and parse it to a byte array so I can send it to my web service. Thanks for your help.

Comment: May be [This SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777155/how-to-get-memory-stream-base64-string-from-image-source) will be helpfule

Comment: can you tell us the image source of ImageContol?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Uploading-and-downloading-images-from-WCF-in-Silverlight.aspx) one is very useful for your problem.

[This](http://daveswersky.com/2009/08/29/silverlight-upload-and-display-image/) one can also guide you in some way.